# How would you connect a table VC with another VC through delegate and protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Okay, so I have this table view, where each row has a label with a string. I want to make it so that if I select a row, the string of that row will be carried to a label of another view controller. I tried using delegate and protocol, but I always keep on getting a nil value for the delegate. The string is not the problem, nor is the table view. It can print the value of the string in the row, but whenever I try to use a delegate, it simply won't work. I added the protocol, established it in the other VC, set it as a delegate, and added the value of the variables in the table view whenever a row is selected. Any suggestion? This is really bothering me.

Comment: You need show code. Especially the `didSelectRow` delegate.

Comment: add your code to check.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this for myself like 5 minutes ago and it worked. The thing i was trying to do is to add a string that i got from one ViewController to an array in another ViewController. It printed in the console nil for me because the array was an optional. But as soon as i removed that question mark and initialized it as an empty array it worked like a clock. And i also wanted to show it in a collectionView, but i forgot to add this

```
Dispatch.main.async{
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

I also used this guide

> http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/pass-information-back-to-the-previous-view-controller/

Hope i helped.